# Error al elaborar archivo pdf con html2pdf

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

```
<?php
   require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
   $objpdf = new Html2pdf('p','A4', 'es', 'true', 'UTF-8');
   $contenido = $objetoPDF->getHtmlFromPage(file_get_contents('pdf.html'));
   $objpdf ->WriteHTML($contenido);
   $objpdf ->output();
   ?>
```

El problema que me arroja es este:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Html2pdf' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\control_admin resubido\print_pdf.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\control_admin resubido\print_pdf.php on line 3

Me podrian ayudar a resolverlo, se los agradeceria.

Comment: Parece que no instaló bien la librería, o que falta algo en la ruta del `autoload`. ¿Lo instalaste a mano o mediante composer?

Comment: Mediante composer en el cmd.

Comment: En el `require_once` pon la ruta absoluta del archivo, parece que hay un problema de rutas y por eso no encuentra el archivo. O, intenta probar así: `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;`

Comment: no tienes la libreria incluida..

Answer (score 0):

**

```
<?php
    // Form sent
    if( isset($_POST['val']) ){
    }


  ob_start();
?>
<page backtop="10mm" backbottom="10mm" backleft="20mm" backright="20mm">
    <page_header> contenido</page_header>
        <h1>Estamos creando un PDF</h1>       <br>
        <b>Ingresa a Codigo Facilito, aprenderás muchas cosas</b><br>
        <a href='http://codigofacilito.com'>Click</a>.<br>  
    <page_footer>contenido</page_footer>
</page>

<?php

    $content = ob_get_clean();
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'./../vendor/autoload.php');
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;


    try
    {
      $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'es', true, 'UTF-8', 3);
      $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
      $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
      $html2pdf->Output('PDF-CF.pdf');
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
      echo $e;
      exit;
    }
```

**

Fíjate que te falta añadir las líneas USE para incluir el uso delas librerias.
En mi caso se me ha borrado el directorio y he vuelto a lanzar la instrucción:

`Ruta_Proyecto`C:\wamp64\www\proyecto_pdf

`Instrucción`>composer require spipu/html2pdf

**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'./../vendor/autoload.php');
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;
```

**